# How do I read a Foxpro 8.0 database from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-foxpro

I need to import tables from foxpro 8.0 to sql server.  How do I read the tables & schema from a foxpro directory/files in C# so I can create the tables in SQL Server and copy the data over?

Answer (score 8):

You can accomplish this through the use of the [GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135981.aspx) method on the OleDb.Connection class.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
    "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=.\\Northwind\\Northwind.dbc;"
);
connection.Open();
DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema(
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables
);

foreach (System.Data.DataRow rowTables in tables.Rows)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(rowTables["table_name"].ToString());
    DataTable columns = connection.GetSchema(
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, 
        new String[] { null, null, rowTables["table_name"].ToString(), null }
    );
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow rowColumns in columns.Rows)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(
            rowTables["table_name"].ToString() + "." +
            rowColumns["column_name"].ToString() + " = " +
            rowColumns["data_type"].ToString()
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ODBCConnection. I know foxpro is using .dbf files.

```
OdbcConnection Conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=C:\\tbl.dbf;");
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl.dbf";
        Conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand MyCommand = new OdbcCommand(SQL,Conn);
        OdbcDataReader dr = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
           //your code
        }
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but right this wouldn't work with versions after VFP6.

Comment: Visual FoxPro dbf is not the same as dBASE

Comment: the thing is this answers the question and not the version problem

Comment: this is correct for .dbf files. as per connection strings found here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/

Answer (score 1):

With exception of the "Driver" providd by RJ's answer, go to MS and get the VFP OleDB provider...  You might have compatibility issues if dealing with a database container.